# Using UIAlertView to conditionally load a web request

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

In the iPhone project I'm currently working on, one of the requirements is that when a user clicks on a link on a page maintained by a `UIViewController` managing a `UIWebView` then a `UIAlertView` should be shown.  The web page pointed to by the link should be loaded only if the user does not click on the alert's cancel button.  A further detail is that this particular controller is a subclass of a base web view controller class, so in some cases request loading needs to be deferred to this super class. In short:

```
1. User clicks on a link
2. Inspect link n webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType: 
3. Depending on the link, show a UIAlertView
4. If the user presses Cancel, the alert is dismissed and the request is NOT loaded
5. If the user presses Continue, the alert is dismissed and the request is loaded
```

I tried to override `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` and then based on the link show the alert. However, then I realized that whatever events occur when one of the alert's buttons is pressed is going to happen in a call back like, `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:`.  I tried doing this and the application locked up.

I'm guessing there's a way to do this but it may not be too straight forward and I should just try showing custom, modal `UIView` that accomplishes the same thing as what I'm trying to do with the alert.

An hits will be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Show the alert and store the original request in some property of your view controller. Then immediately return `NO` from the delegate method (`shouldStartLoadWithRequest:...`).

Implement `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` and load the request you stored earlier in the property, if the user selects Continue... (if Cancel is selected, you don't have to do anything).